# $scope.$apply in AngularJS - Function executed each time is the last defined function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

If I call the code below inside a loop of asynchronous HTTP requests I get latter response. Any suggestions on where I could be going wrong?

NOTE: This is essentially pseudo code.

```
function successful_request(site) {
    console.log('In: ' + site.id);
    $scope.$apply(function() { console.log('Out: ' + site.id); }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
In: 1
In: 2
In: 3
Out: 3
Out: 3
Out: 3
```

I hope I've made sense here. I suspect it's a case of how I'm calling $scope.$apply but I'm not sure what I should do differently.

Comment: Can you make sure to paste the correct code? obviously `$scope.$apply(function() { console.log('Out: ' + site.id); }` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you declared the variable `site` globally / outside of the asynchronous loop scope.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. I can see what's going on now, thanks for this. I'm using the code with Google's Geocoder but I've found an article relating to function closure which may help me out here. Thanks for circling this one out for me!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of side effect is fairly common when running a closure inside of a loop, I can't really tell from your example but you may want to take a look through the following link to see if it applies to your situation. [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Just by placing the asynchronous call inside a function and calling that from the loop, my problems were resolved. My understanding is that this is because the function preserved the arguments given, thus the asynchronous callback would have the preserved variables in its scope.